# Saving bash variable *after* a command have run

Tags: bash

I have the following git pre-commit hook:

```
echo '\n Running "yarn lint"...'
cd web
lintCheck=$(yarn lint)

if [[ "$lintCheck" == *" No ESLint warnings or errors"* ]]; then
  echo "✅ Linting looks good!";
else
  echo "❌ Linting error ❌";
  exit 1
fi
```

I want to display the output from `yarn lint` with normal behavior. I want to see messages as they come using the standard formatting of messages in real time.

The closest solution I have that doesn't run the same command twice looks like this:

```
echo '\n Running "yarn lint"...'
cd web
lintCheck=$(yarn lint)

echo $lintCheck # <-- LOOK HERE

if [[ "$lintCheck" == *" No ESLint warnings or errors"* ]]; then
  echo "✅ Linting looks good!";
else
  echo "❌ Linting error ❌";
  exit 1
fi
```

However, it outputs the text without regular font color and on one single line, all at the same time.

I've got a tip to use `tee`, but as I understand it it's used for file saving, and not for variables.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Put a valid [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) and paste your script at https://shellcheck.net for validation/recommendation.

Comment: Use the exit status of `yarn` rather than examining its output: `if yarn lint; then echo "Good"; else echo "bad"; exit 1; done`.

Comment: Git itself is not actually relevant here: everything here is up to yarnlint (i.e., what you're running) and bash itself (i.e., the scripting language you're using). You may want to add the [tag:yarnpkg] or [tag:yarnpkg-v2] tag.

Comment: Also look into [pre-commit](https://pre-commit.com/); you may be reinventing a wheel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `echo $lintCheck`
> However, it outputs the text without regular font color and on one single line, all at the same time.

The missing line breaks come from the unquoted variable expansion, which does all kind of stuff like word splitting and so on.  Use `echo "$lintCheck"` to keep the linebreaks.

The missing colors *probably* come from `yarn` itself. Programs can detect if they run interactively or in a pipe/script and adjust their output accordingly.
I cannot try this myself, but from https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/  ...

> Force ANSI color output
>
> Yarn utilizes the chalk terminal colors library and will respect an environment variable setting FORCE_COLOR=true, e.g. to make script tasks output color when the terminal is not a tty (e.g., in CI environments.)

it seems you can use ...

```
lintCheck=$(FORCE_COLOR=true yarn lint)
echo "$lintCheck"
```

But that will give you the output only *after* `yarn lint` completed. To print the output as soon it is produced, try [writing to a file descriptor](https://serverfault.com/a/989827)

```
{ lintCheck=$(FORCE_COLOR=true yarn lint | tee /dev/fd/3); } 3>&1
```

However, the whole reason you try to capture the output in a variable looks a bit like an XY problem. Are you sure you need the output, and cannot just use the exit status of `yarn lint`?